# Show Spring Boot buildInfo() version rendered inside JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, gradle

I am generating the build info of my Spring Boot application using the following Gradle snippet:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

This makes sure that a file called `/META-INF/build-info.properties` is created during build inside the WAR artifact with the property `build.version=1.2.3` (and a few others)

I am building a WAR, instead of a JAR because I rely on rendering legacy JSPs.

Inside these JSPs I need to print this version. I have tried the following:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('build.version')" var="version" />

<p>Version is: ${version}</p>
```

But that remains empty. It looks like I can access anything from my `application.properties` this way, but not from the other generated `build-info.properties`

What is the proper way to get this version information to the JSPs?

Please note this is a legacy application which limits my options:

- I cannot switch from JSPs to modern alternatives such as Thymeleaf
- These JSPs are fairly simple. I do not want to create (and duplicate) Controllers to set the necessary variables

**Alternative**

I found the following alternative which works, but is not desirable, since it duplicates the behavior of the `buildInfo()` plugin which I need anyway in other places in my application:

- Add `application.version=${project.version}` to my own `application.properties`
- Add `processResources { expand(project.properties) }` to `build.gradle`
- Access `@environment.getProperty('application.version')` inside the JSP

Answer (score 0):

`META-INF/build-info.properties` is a Spring Boot Actuator config file, and as such is not part of the normal application properties.

It's contents is available separately via the [`BuildProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/info/BuildProperties.html) bean.

In your controller:

```
@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;

. . .
    String version = buildProperties.getVersion();
```

(Note that the bean is only defined if `build-info.properties` exists, so better to wire it as `required=false`)

Or via SpEL:

```
@Value("#{buildProperties.get('version')}")
String version;
```

In the JSP with something like this (untested):

```
<spring:eval expression="#{buildProperties.get('version')}" var="version" />

<p>Version is: ${version}</p>
```

Comment: Where does `buildProperties` come from? Like I wrote in my original question, I need this functionality in many JSPs. I don't want to create an identical controller just for passing this value.

Comment: It comes from [`spring-boot-actuator`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.boot%20AND%20a:spring-boot-actuator&core=gav)